# как задать разное значение отступов между различными строками в css?

Tags: html, css, html5, вёрстка, figma

Дан макет страницы в Figma в котором между строками разный отступ:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как элементами css сделать отступ между второй и третьей строкой?

Answer (score 0):

Там используется такая конструкция:

```
<div class= "all">
    <div class= "first">Первый отдел с текстом</div>
    <div class= "second">Второй отдел с текстом</div>
</div>
```

Далее просто прописываем нужную высоту для отступа.

```
.all {
    line-height: Нужное значение;
}
.first {
    line-height: Нужное значение;
}
.second {
    line-height: Нужное значение;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Это два разных параграфа.

HTML:

```
<p class="first">Первый параграф</p>
<p class="second">Второй параграф</p>
```

CSS:

```
.first {
    line-height: ;
    margin-bottom ;
}

.second {
    line-height: ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Просто оберните каждую строку в тег `<p>` как показано ниже.

```html
<p>© 2012-2020 Управляющая компания Объединенной сети «Лугана Хотелс»</p>
<p>Представленная на сайте информация носит справочный характер и не является публичной офертой</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

ты можешь сделать отступы при помощи тега `<p>` в конце предложения.

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).